# DTD and root items

Tags: xml

I need to import data from third party sites into my own site and I'm using XPath to do so. I've created a PHP script that grabs the data I want and turn it into XML.

Now, I had to create my very own DTD and this is where the issue lies.

When I try to validate the XML feed using W3C, is says that the feed doesnt have a root element. But I thought I did - what am I doing wrong?

DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE item [
<!ELEMENT item (id,company,homepage,language,title,link,guid,description,pubDate,creator,contact,mail,phone,region,image,price,term)>
<!ELEMENT id (#ID)>
<!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT homepage (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT link (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT guid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pubDate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT creator (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT contact (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mail (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT region (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT term (#PCDATA)>
 ]>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE item SYSTEM "buysell.dtd">
<item>
  <id>'.$num.'</id>
  <company>'.$company.'</company>
  <homepage>'.$homepage.'</homepage>
  <language>sv</language>
  <title>'.$title.'</title>
  <link>'.$anchor.'</link>
  <guid>'.$anchor.'</guid>
  <description>'.$title.'</description>
  <pubDate>'.$date.'</pubDate>
  <creator>'.$company.'</creator>
  <contact>'.$contact.'</contact>
  <mail>'.$mail.'</mail>
  <phone>'.$phone.'</phone>
  <region>'.$region.'</region>
  <image>'.$image.'</image>
  <price>'.$price.'</price>
  <term>'.$term.'</term>
</item>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems here which need to be fixed:

- The DTD should not have the document type declaration (enclosing
  !DOCTYPE structure), but must be just a list of !ELEMENT
  declarations.
- There is no keyword "#ID" in XML 1.0, this should probably just be
  "#PCDATA"
- Your document instance has a spurious "';" string after the closing
  end tag, and so is not well formed.

Fix these up, and all will be well ...